# Send message to different activities from a single handler

Tags: android, handler

I have a handler and I have to send responses to different activities for the same condition.Is it possible?Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handler will work only on the thread on which it was originally created on.

What exactly is your scenario when you need to send response to more than one activity at a time?
Maybe you should just implement an EventListener and EventDispatcher so you EventDispatcher will receive events (ex. network) and it will notify to its listeners (who ever registered to its events).

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
 startActivityForResult();
```